Where can I find the results file(s) of the openscap anaconda addon (org_fedora_oscap) after RHEL8 installation?
I'm performing a RHEL8 installation using a kickstart file with the following addon defined:
%addon org_fedora_oscap
    content-type = scap-security-guide
    datastream-id = scap_org.open-scap_datastream_from_xccdf_ssg-rhel8-xccdf.xml
    xccdf-id = scap_org.open-scap_cref_ssg-rhel8-xccdf.xml
    profile = xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_stig_gui
%end

I'd like to investigate the results of the scan/remediation, which I assume are captured in results files somewhere on the filesystem post-installation.  I have not been able to find any documentation that tells me where these files are located.  Do results files get produced by the org_fedora_oscap addon?  If so, where are they located?

The results should be located under /root/openscap_data.
